# add class to parent on click with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I currently have this, it was working in jsFiddle, though its giving me errors, and not working when I use it outside of fiddle.

```
$('.down-photo').click(function() {
      $(this).parent('.img-mask').toggleClass('hide');
});​
```

Firebug says:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Token ILLEGAL

I'm newer to javascript and jQuery so I'm not sure what's wrong or what that error means.

Thanks!

Comment: Try `parents` or `closest` instead.

Comment: Post a link to your fiddle.  You may have a bad cut-and-paste when you are copying it outside.

Comment: @RicardoLohmann -- He has a syntax error.  Randomly changing methods won't/can't help with that.

Comment: Thanks! here yah go! http://jsfiddle.net/dvCmR/132/

Comment: That fiddle doesn't include the code from your question, but in your question's code there seems to be a non-printing character after the last `;`. So that could be illegal token.

Comment: This happens alot when you copy code from jsfiddle, in this case it is `â€‹` after your function

Comment: interesting! how do I fix that? just retype it?

Comment: Retype it, yes. It seems to be character 8203, which is a Unicode zero-width space. (You'll notice, if you edit the text in your question, that if you put the cursor to the left of that last `;` and then press the right arrow a few times it takes one more keypress than you'd expect to get to the next line - that's the character I mean.)

Comment: That worked! Make it an answer! :) It's a yes for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code in your question there is a non-printing character after the last semicolon. It seems to be character 8203, a Unicode zero-width space. That's the illegal token that Firebug is telling you about.

You'll notice, if you edit the text in your question, that if you put the cursor to the left of that last semicolon and then press the right arrow a few times it takes one more keypress than you'd expect to get to the next line - that's the character I mean.

Delete that character, or manually retype the line (rather than copy/pasting), and it should be fine.

Answer (score -2):

I fixed your error. `$.appendTo()` takes a selector, not a jquery object. 
Try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/dvCmR/133/    (line 4)

Comment: According to [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/), `.appendTo()` takes _"A selector, element, HTML string, or jQuery object"_.